# Removing weak ciphers from openssl

Tags: security, ssl, openssl, cryptography, tls1.2

I am trying to remove weak ciphers from openssl ciphersuites list. When I run 'openssl ciphers -v' I see ciphers with SSLv3 and TLSv1 as well. I want to avoid weak ciphers and restrict ciphers list to only TLSv1.2 and greater.

Is there any way I can do this by updating openssl.cnf file.

I tried approaches from https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/7562 and https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man5/config.html

```
openssl_conf = default_conf

[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
```

With above configuration when I run 'openssl ciphers -v' command, I expect to see only TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3 ciphers, but I see no changes in ciphers listed and all weak ciphers are also present.

We can restrict ciphers suites list by removing them from openssl code and building and installing it. Please suggest if there is any other easier way.

From openssl man pages - https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man5/config.html, has this statement 'The system default configuration with name system_default if present will be applied during any creation of the SSL_CTX structure.'

that means, are these openssl.conf changes applied only to certificate file generation and not to the openssl execution?

Any help or clarification of my understanding is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could get only required ciphers by changing openssl.cnf file.

Adding this default conf line at the top of the file

```
# System default
openssl_conf = default_conf
```

Appending below conf at the bottom of the file.

```
[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_section

[ssl_section]
system_default = system_default_section

[system_default_section]
CipherString = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Ciphersuites = TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
```

I used **Ciphersuites** to specify TLSv1.3 ciphers and **CipherString** to restrict other versions.