# How to configure 'TLS1.2 only' in OpenSSL 1.0.2 config file?

Tags: python, openssl, tls1.2, configuration-files

I would like to update the configuration of OpenSSL 1.0.2 (specifically 1.0.2k-fips as found on AWS's Amazon Linux 2 AMIs), so that any client using OpenSSL refuses TLSv1.1, TLSv1, or anything lower that is not TLSv1.2.

I have learned that for OpenSSL 1.1+ the OpenSSL config file (e.g., /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf on Amazon Linux 2, or /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf on Debian derivatives, or whatever `$OPENSSL_CONF` points to), one can specify `openssl_conf` -> a section with `ssl_conf` -> a section with `system_default` -> a section with `MinProtocol=TLSv1.2`.

However, that `ssl_conf` syntax is unknown in OpenSSL 1.0.2k, and instead it tries to load `libssl_conf.so` which fails because that shared library does not exist.

So *my question:* Is it possible to configure OpenSSL 1.0.2 to fail if one tries to use TLSv1.1 or below?  At least if the `openssl` binary tries, or any Python code that I don't control using [the ssl module for Python 3.9 or lower](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ssl.html)?

---

Additional information: At least on Amazon Linux 2 with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips, using `grep` I cannot even find the string MinProtocol in any OpenSSL 1.0.2 related binary or shared library.  (But it *does* occur in an OpenSSL 1.1.1s `libssl.so.1.1` that is shipped with an agent I happened to have on that same AL2 system.)

So that confirms my suspicion that the answer to my question is: No, this is not possible.

Comment: this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67816301/removing-weak-ciphers-from-openssl

Comment: to enable TLS 1.2 only, you should restrict the cipher list, did you try to use the configuration linked in the previous comment? here is a useful link where you can find the cipher list for each protocol version : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/213616/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-cipher-suites-supported-in-a-specific-tls-version

Comment: @Lety Thanks!  But https://stackoverflow.com/q/67816301/223837 does not help, this works with OpenSSL 1.1.1+, but (as I tried to document in my question) I cannot get that to work with 1.0.2.  And restrict the cipher list would require setting `CipherString` (and `Ciphersuites` for TLSv1.3), but for those I have the same issue as for `MinProtocol`: I cannot find a way for OpenSSL 1.0.2 to pick up those settings.

Comment: ok, if it is not possible to restrict cipher in openssl configuration, you could restict it when you try to open a tls connection in your client. During handshake both server and client exchange information about cipher to choose which one is in common. Here another usefult link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, as a self-answer (to replace an answer that was deleted for looking ChatGPT-generated): OpenSSL 1.0.2 does not support configuring allowed SSL/TLS protocol versions or cipher suites through its configuration file.

Evidence:

- OpenSSL 1.0.2 binaries (at least OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips as shipped with Amazon Linux 2 AMIs from AWS) don't contain the string `MinProtocol`.
- The `ssl_conf` configuration seems to have been added OpenSSL 1.1.0, per e.g. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918727.  And the `system_default` configuration inside of `ssl_conf` is automatically applied since OpenSSL 1.1.1, per [commit 8a5ed9dc "Apply system_default configuration on SSL_CTX_new()."](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/8a5ed9dce8ee36b4bb05cb928fa7a01aba6d8e41)  It is those features, apparently, that make it possible to put TLS configurations in the OpenSSL config file (`$OPENSSL_CONF` with a distro-specific default), in addition to calling some OpenSSL API.
- None of the procedures seen in comments on this question or in other answers, actually work.  They either ignore the configuration file change, or fail to load the configuration, for example with `could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:187:filename(libssl_conf.so): libssl_conf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

(As ChatGPT pointed out, there are various ways where a cooperating client can give OpenSSL such settings, e.g., via its API, via the `openssl` command line, or via Python's `ssl` default SSL context; but that was not the point of this question.)

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific rules for the named sections in config file as mentioned in:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man5/config.html

"The **first section** of a configuration file is special and is referred to as the **default section**. This section is usually unnamed and spans from the start of file until the first named section. **When a name is being looked up** it is first **looked up in** a **named section (if any)** and then the default section."

So same MinProtocol field used in other version must work here as well. Maybe its just not mentioned on the man page.

Comment: I was not asking about section names, but more importantly, I was asking about OpenSSL *1.0.2*.  I know that the way the OpenSSL configuration is used has changed in 1.1.1, including things that are loaded by default.  But you are saying, I think, "Even with OpenSSL 1.0.2, you could try to put MinProtocol=TLSv1.2" in the very first section."  I am going to try that.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but `MinProtocol=TLSv1.2` in the first (or `[default]`) section is completely ignored by OpenSSL 1.0.2, it looks like.  I just checked, and (at least on Amazon Linux 2 with 1.0.2k) I cannot even find the string `MinProtocol` in any OpenSSL 1.0.2 related binary or shared library.

Answer (score 0):

Right, `MinProtocol` is not yet supported by your version of openssl.

Instead, you can configure a list of ciphers you want to allow. When selecting only those which implement TLS 1.2 you get what you want to achieve.
First, produce a list of all ciphers supported by your version of openssl which implement TLS 1.2:

```
openssl ciphers 'TLSv1.2'
```

Output will be a colon (“:”) separated list of those ciphers.

In your configuration file add the following line to your system_default section:

```
CipherString = <colon (“:”) separated list of ciphers copied from the command above>
```

`CipherString` limits the ciphers of V.1.2 and below to the specified list. This parameter is not related to TLS V.1.3 and above. With this config you support all TLS 1.2 ciphers and above. If you want V.1.2 only (no TLS V.1.3), than you would need to clear the list of TLS V.1.3 ciphers, which is specified by parameter `Ciphersuites`:

```
Ciphersuites =
```

Sample (I randomly shortened the list here):

```
openssl_conf = default_conf

[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_section

[ssl_section]
system_default = system_default_section

[system_default_section]
CipherString = TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Ciphersuites =
```

Now you can go ahead and be even more picky in your selection of ciphers.

To check the success of your configuration, issue the following command before and after your configuration change:

```
openssl ciphers -v
```

Comment: Could you please clarify how I 'point to' this `system_default_section`?  Since just adding it doesn't make `openssl` use it, it seems.  And using `ssl_conf` gives me the shared library loading issue I mentioned in my questions...

Comment: I have added the pointers to the example.

Comment: Well, but that is the whole issue: using `ssl_conf` Iin the section that `openssl_conf` points to) gives me
`Error configuring OpenSSL` `140682803439520:error:25066067:DSO support routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:187:filename(libssl_conf.so): libssl_conf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` in OpenSSL 1.0.2...

Comment: I understand. I was so much focused on describing a substitution for parameter `MinProtocol`, that I didn't realize this whole `ssl_conf` does not work for you. I don't have a solution for that, I am afraid. All workarounds I find for openssl v.1.0 not compatible with an `openssl.cnf` is to comment the `ssl_conf` line.

Comment: And all this is already in the comments below your question. Oh my, I didn't see it, sorry.